# Template vs plugin which is best for WordPress performance?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, plugins

I need some future, I know a little bit about how to write code for WordPress. My question is, is it better to use a template or plugin for site performance.

As I know plugin's code always runs through the whole site, but I am confused about the template is also every time run globally or on a specific page.

If template code is not run every time, them seems to me that using a template is good for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends. Under what circumstance does the code need to run?

The code in a theme's `function.php` will get executed on every WordPress load, just the same as with plugins.

The way you decide when the code runs is through the use of hooks and filters. This is how you begin to position the execution of your code, you don't do it by "placing" it in theme or plugin.

If you want to run the code on the frontend only, a good hook to start with is the `wp` hook. This is run only when a non-admin/frontend page loads.

Depending on the code, if it's only on the admin side, you could try `admin_init`

Hooking into `init` or `wp_loaded` will run the code in all complete WordPress loads (unless execution is terminated early for some reason).

Start with understanding the hooks and decide based on what you need your code to do, where and when to hook your code, and it's probably best to make your own custom plugin, unless it's functionality specific to the active theme, so that if you change your theme in the future, your plugin doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: I want to know, if I use a template for a specific page, will this template  load every time.. thanks for helping me

Comment: No. A particular template file will only be loaded when the page(s) that use the template are requested.